# How to count a column in database and if empty return 0 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table where I want to count total entries in one column. But if the entire column is empty, I want the count to return 0 (meaning there are zero entries)

This is what I tried, but when I use echo it returns blank. In the database it is blank, but I want it to return 0 when column recall is empty.

CODE:

```
$chartsql = "SELECT recall from report where child_id='$childId'"; 
$ChartRes = mysqli_query($con,$chartsql);

while ($ChartRow=mysqli_fetch_array($ChartRes)){
    $recall[] = $ChartRow['recall1'];
}

foreach($recall as $index=>$value) {
    if($value === null) unset($recall[$index]);
}
$count_recall = count($recall);

if($count_recall = ''){
    $count_recall1 = 0;

}

echo $count_recall;
```

Also, in the recall column, there are null entries as well as blank entries. So I want to ignore the nulls, but if all other entries are blank then it should return zero. If there are some blank and some valid entries, then it should only count the valid entries and not what is blank.

It should only return 0 if it is completely empty, ignoring nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL count function instead:

```
$chartsql = "SELECT count(child_id) as totalitems from report where child_id='$childId' and recall is not null and recall != ''";
$ChartRes = mysqli_query($con,$chartsql);
$ChartRow = mysqli_fetch_array($ChartRes);
$count_recall = $ChartRow['totalitems'];
```

Never use PHP for counting, when you can use SQL for your result, because:

- When you have many rows, you will have performance issue.
- You can easily do it inside your query and have cleaner codes.
- Debugging is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

How about `count(*)`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html

```
$chartsql = "SELECT count(*) from report where child_id='$childId'" and recall is not null and recall != ''";
```

Comment: This is returning 1 when I echo count(recall); Is there a way to get it to return 0 since it is blank?

Comment: @TaahiraCarter Because you are counting how many rows returned from that query not the real value of the `count(*)`. you don't need those php codes anymore after this query. you have the total items count in `$ChartRow['count(*)']`. I recommend to use `SELECT count(child_id) as totalitems` and get it with `$ChartRow['totalitems']`.

Comment: @ICE But I need to know how many rows have a value in it. So if column "recall" has 5 rows and 3 rows have a value but 2 rows are blank, then $count_recall value should be 3. Because only 3 of the rows have a value. And if all 5 rows in column "recall" are blank, then I need it to return 0. This is important as I need to use this value in a math equation.

Comment: @TaahiraCarter He added `and recall is not null and recall != ''";` to the query just for that. you can do that with `IS NOT NULL` in mysql.

Comment: @ICE But when I tried that it kept returning blank. Even if 5 rows had a value it kept returning blank when it should return 5. and if all were empty it returned blank when it should return 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $chartsql = 
  "SELECT (count(id) - (
       SELECT count(id) 
       FROM report 
       WHERE attributeName LIKE ''))
   FROM report"; 
?>
```

All you need to do is substract the total of rows to the amout of empty rows. It should do the job

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you could simplify it by:

assign only valid value to $recall array

add zero to returned value from count() to make it an integer

```
<?php
$chartsql = "SELECT recall from report where child_id='$childId'"; 
$ChartRes = mysqli_query($con,$chartsql);

while ($ChartRow=mysqli_fetch_array($ChartRes)){
    if(!is_null($ChartRow['recall1'])){
        $recall[] = $ChartRow['recall1'];
    }
}

$count_recall = count($recall) + 0;

echo $count_recall;
```